# Filtering nested array against another nested array without loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, nested, reduce

I have a nested array I would like to compare and filter against another nested array.

```
const array1 = [
{
   id:1,
   nights: [{date: '2022-07-24', status: 'booked'},
            {date: '2022-07-26', status: 'booked'}]
},
{
   id:2,
   nights: [{date: '2022-07-24', status: 'booked'},
            {date: '2022-07-25', status: 'booked'}
            {date: '2022-07-26', status: 'booked'}]
}
];


const array2 = [
{
   id:1,
   days: [{date: '2022-07-24', breakdown: [...]},
          {date: '2022-07-25', breakdown: [...]},
          {date: '2022-07-26', breakdown: [...]}]
},
{
   id:2,
   days: [{date: '2022-07-24', breakdown: [...],
          {date: '2022-07-25', breakdown: [...],
          {date: '2022-07-26', breakdown: [...]}]
}
];
```

Essentially I want to filter array2 so it matches the dates in array1 and drops the extra day it has in the element with an id of 1.

The filtered array should look something like this:

```
const filteredArray2 = [
{
   id:1,
   days: [{date: '2022-07-24', breakdown: [...]},
          {date: '2022-07-26', breakdown: [...]}]
},
{
   id:2,
   days: [{date: '2022-07-24', breakdown: [...],
          {date: '2022-07-25', breakdown: [...],
          {date: '2022-07-26', breakdown: [...]}]
}
];
```

I have tried a couple of map, include, filter and reduce methods to achieve my desired output but I'm getting lost in the sauce with the nesting. First time posting and new to JS, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are the IDs guaranteed to match between the two arrays?

Comment: You only want to filter the element with id 1?

Comment: Ids are not guaranteed to match. But each array is guaranteed to be the same length. Hoping to do a check with some() or includes() where the days array is filtered to match the nights array based on the date values. Both should be filtered to match based on array1's dates for each element

Answer (score 0):

Use `find()` to find the item in `array1` with the matching `id`.

Then use `filter()` to filter the `days` array. The filter function uses `.some()` to check if there's a matching date in the `nights` array of the above item.

```js
const array1 = [
{
   id:1,
   nights: [{date: '2022-07-24', status: 'booked'},
            {date: '2022-07-26', status: 'booked'}]
},
{
   id:2,
   nights: [{date: '2022-07-24', status: 'booked'},
            {date: '2022-07-25', status: 'booked'},
            {date: '2022-07-26', status: 'booked'}]
}
];


const array2 = [
{
   id:1,
   days: [{date: '2022-07-24', breakdown: []},
          {date: '2022-07-25', breakdown: []},
          {date: '2022-07-26', breakdown: []}]
},
{
   id:2,
   days: [{date: '2022-07-24', breakdown: []},
          {date: '2022-07-25', breakdown: []},
          {date: '2022-07-26', breakdown: []}]
}
];

const filteredArray2 = array2.map(item2 => {
  let item1 = array1.find(el => el.id == item2.id);
  if (item1) {
    let new_days = item2.days.filter(d => item1.nights.some(n => n.date = d.date));
    return { ...item2,
      days: new_days
    };
  } else {
    return { ...item2
    };
  }
});

console.log(filteredArray2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to transform the array, you want to use a map. Using `flatMap` will allow you to also filter out items by returning an empty array, `[]`, if the ids aren't guaranteed to match.

```js
const filteredArray2 = array2.flatMap(({ id, days}) => {
```

Inside of the `flatMap`, you want to find the corresponding object in `array1` based on the `id`.

```js
  const filterObject = array1.find((obj) => obj.id === id);
```

Now you want to do one of those things. If the item exists in `array1`, use it to filter the object in `array2`. Otherwise, ignore it by returning an empty array (`[]`).

```js
  return filterObject ? [{
    id,
    days: days.filter((day) => filterObject.nights.find(night => day.date === night.date)) 
  }] : [];
```

Putting it all together

```js
const array1 = [
{
   id:1,
   nights: [{date: '2022-07-24', status: 'booked'},
            {date: '2022-07-26', status: 'booked'}]
},
{
   id:2,
   nights: [{date: '2022-07-24', status: 'booked'},
            {date: '2022-07-25', status: 'booked'}
            {date: '2022-07-26', status: 'booked'}]
}
];


const array2 = [
{
   id:1,
   days: [{date: '2022-07-24', breakdown: []},
          {date: '2022-07-25', breakdown: []},
          {date: '2022-07-26', breakdown: []}]
},
{
   id:2,
   days: [{date: '2022-07-24', breakdown: [],
          {date: '2022-07-25', breakdown: [],
          {date: '2022-07-26', breakdown: []}]
}
];

const filteredArray2 = array2.flatMap(({ id, days}) => {
    const filterObject = array1.find((obj) => obj.id === id);
    return filterObject ? [{
      id,
      days: days.filter((day) => filterObject.nights.find(night => day.date === night.date)) 
    }] : [];
});
```

Comment: If there were other elements with duplicated id's i.e another element with id of 2, could filter be used instead of find to avoid losing it in the filtered array?